# Como verificar se todos os valores são iguais em um vetor no r

Tags: array, r

Tenho como resposta de uma função os vetores RMSEA, GFI, NFI e CFI que podem conter valores todos iguais. Na sequencia utilizo o algoritmo abaixo para testar a normalidade através do teste de shapiro-wilk. Quando os valores são todos iguais ele retorna erro da forma

Error in shapiro.test(RMSEA) : all 'x' values are identical

e o restante do algoritmo falha por causa desse problema.
Como posso verificar se os valores dos vetores são todos iguais e não rodar o teste neste caso.

```
# TESTE DE NORMALIDADE

  t1 <- shapiro.test(RMSEA) 
  t2 <- shapiro.test(GFI) 
  t3 <- shapiro.test(NFI) 
  t4 <- shapiro.test(CFI) 

  estt <- as.numeric(c(t1$statistic, t2$statistic, t3$statistic,t4$statistic))
  valorp <- c(t1$p.value, t2$p.value, t3$p.value, t4$p.value)
  resultados <- cbind(estt, valorp)
  rownames(resultados) <- c("SHAPIRO-WILK RMSEA","SHAPIRO-WILK GFI","SHAPIRO-WILK NFI","SHAPIRO-WILK CFI")
  colnames(resultados) <- c("Estatística", "p")
  print(resultados)
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode simplesmente comparar o primeiro elemento com cada elemento usando `==`. Isso irá retornar um vetor de `TRUE` ou `FALSE` e `all` testará se todos os elementos deste vetor são iguais à `TRUE` (`all` é o mesmo que `identical(TRUE, x)`)

```
  x <- 1:10
  y <- rep(2, 10)

  all(x == x[1])
  # [1] FALSE

  all(y == y[1])
  # [1] TRUE
```

Ref: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-August/078129.html